# Yesod Editable Table

Tags: haskell, yesod

I need to make a table with an editable column. Each row is a separate record. I want to be able to display hundreds of records, perform edits to them and then submit them back to the server for updating. I am not sure this is really supported by the forms infrastructure.

Is there a way to make a repeatable form such that I would get a list of results back? This seems to be the closest solution I can envision without writing my own in javascript. Any ideas on this would be welcome.

Comment: Do the edits you will perform include insertion, deletion, and reordering? If you can do without these things, then implementing this *could* be fairly simple. If you need these things, then you almost certainly need some JavaScript for a smooth user experience (JQuery has some pluigns to help with this sort of thing), and serializing to and from Yesod forms could get complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. Just use one of the full featured js grids like jqgrid or extjs if you want the full pack of UI components.
I use jqgrid with yesod, edit rows both in grid and in outside panel and submit the changes back.

I think the problem with your approach is that you found your hammer (yesod forms library) and now looking for a nail.
You don't have to use every bit of yesod just because its there.

Comment: Actually the data grid I use is a modified version of editablegrid. I was just wondering if haskell forms supported this.

Comment: If your grid can submit back via post, then yesod forms can most likely process the input. But you will loose most of their functionality (rendering, data validation etc).